# Weird Options Menu using Theme.AppCompat.Light on Android version < 5.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I have an app with minSdkVersion = 8. I am using the following theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
```

On Android version less than 5.0, the drop down menu looks that weird: 
[image]

Anyone knows why? How can we fix that? I need to use AppCompat theme since I am required to have a colored status bar and other features on 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be an issue with Appcompat library. Once I updated it from 22.2 to 22.2.1, the problem got fixed.